# how to destructure an object and pass the result as argument in a class constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class Cat {
  constructor(words, feet) {
    //this.meow(words);
    this.words = words;
    this.feet = feet;
  }
  meow() {
    console.log(`meow${this.words}${this.feet}`);
  }
}

class Tiger {
  constructor(words) {
    this.words = words;
    //this.rowr(words);
  }
  rowr() {
    console.log(`rowr${this.words}`);
  }
}
const param = {
  words: 'abc',
  feet: 2,
}
const cat = new Cat(...param);
console.log(cat.meow())
```

I got `meowundefinedundefined`

Why is that? Note that I have es6 babel enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to spread an object into the params. You can only spread an object into another object. To destructure it use curly braces in the constructor definition.

**Note:** object [rest/spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) is still a [stage 3 proposal](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/), and requires a [babel transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) to work.

```js
class Cat {
  constructor({ words, feet }) { // destructure the object
    //this.meow(words);
    this.words = words;
    this.feet = feet;
  }
  meow() {
    console.log(`meow${this.words}${this.feet}`);
  }
}

class Tiger {
  constructor(words) {
    this.words = words;
    //this.rowr(words);
  }
  rowr() {
    console.log(`rowr${this.words}`);
  }
}
const param = {
  words: 'abc',
  feet: 2,
}
const cat = new Cat(param);
cat.meow() // meow doesn't return anything, so console.log it will give you undefined
```

Another option is to destructure it outside, and then assign it to the constructor:

```js
class Cat {
  constructor(words, feet) {
    //this.meow(words);
    this.words = words;
    this.feet = feet;
  }
  meow() {
    console.log(`meow${this.words}${this.feet}`);
  }
}

class Tiger {
  constructor(words) {
    this.words = words;
    //this.rowr(words);
  }
  rowr() {
    console.log(`rowr${this.words}`);
  }
}
const { words, feet } = {
  words: 'abc',
  feet: 2,
}
const cat = new Cat(words, feet);
cat.meow() // meow doesn't return anything, so console.log it will give you undefined
```

Comment: *"You can only spread an object into another object."* Not in ES2015 or any other released version. It will come this year though: https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md

Answer (score 1):

You can't destructure an object like that to fill params for a method. you should rather try destructuring an array to pass to the constructor or change the constructor to receive an object instead. words and feet are undefined because they never get passed to the constructure as you would expect.

```js
class Cat {
  constructor(words, feet) {
    //this.meow(words);
    this.words = words;
    this.feet = feet;
  }
  meow() {
    console.log(`meow${this.words}${this.feet}`);
  }
}

class Tiger {
  constructor(words) {
    this.words = words;
    //this.rowr(words);
  }
  rowr() {
    console.log(`rowr${this.words}`);
  }
}

const p = ['abc', 2];
const icat = new Cat(...p); //right
icat.meow(); // meowabc2
```

Checkout [this codepen](https://codepen.io/gastonche/pen/VQKxJL?editors=1112).

Comment: interesting alternative, just that it lose the benefit of having same object name as it passed it. very nice though!

Answer (score 0):

Try spreading an array items. E.g.:

```
const words = 'abc';
const feet = 2;
const param = [
    words,
    feet
];
```